# API V3 - set the zoom -1 from the zoom required to fit the markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like my map to initially zoom out -1 from zoom determined by bounds.
If I do the following, it just zooms in/out, but I want to set the zoom level "a little bigger".

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

For the reasons quite well known I can't use map.setZoom afterwards.

Is there some simple way to do this?

Comment: 'reasons quite well known' - please elaborate

Comment: sorry,as fitBounds is asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to create an event listener for the map `idle` event.  Once `fitbounds` has done its thing, the idle event will be triggered.

If you need to do it every time you fit the bounds then create a custom fitbounds method

```
var fitBounds = function(map, bounds) {
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
       this.setZoom(this.getZoom() - 1);
   });
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Notice we use the `addListenerOnce` method instead of the normal `addListener`.

The problem with this method though is you will still see the initial bounds set for a split second before the map zooms out.

Comment: +1 for addListenerOnce instead of addListener.  I'll update my answer to use that too

Answer (score 0):

You could use an event listener on `zoom_changed`:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();

    map.setZoom(zoomLevel-1);
});
```